# Random default image for a CCK image field

Tags: entities, media

Is it possible to use a random default image for a CCK image field, if the user doesn't provide an image?

Answer (score 2):

Module called [image field random](https://drupal.org/project/image_field_random) does the job you specified.

> Description:
>
> Populates an image field with a random image on save.

Answer (score 1):

CCK imagefield provides settings to have a default image when user doesn't provide any input image. Checkout page `admin/content/node-type/[my-content-type]/fields/[my-image-field]`, `Default image` fieldset.

For random images check devel generate module.

Answer (score 1):

The module that implements that CCK field has a setting for the default image to use for the field, but it's not randomly chosen; the image will be the same, when the user doesn't provide an image.
As far as I know, there aren't modules that alter the settings of ImageField, and add a "Use a random image" option.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure this with a view and some node template changes.

Set up a view for the random image display with sort > global > random

Have the view choose from a library of images

Have node template check if the user uploaded a file for the imagefield; if so, it prints the image; if not, if prints the view:

```
<?php if (field_imagefield_name[0]['view']): ?>
    <?php print field_imagefield_name[0]['view'] ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php print views_embed_view('random_image_view_name','view_display') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, the random global display does not work with page caching turned on (at least in D6), so you may instead want to use a [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) that does not rotate, but does display a random image each time the page is loaded (those are all settings within views slidehow). That should work with page caching.